# How I can get new unique id for each new object in Realm?

Tags: swift, realm

I try create objects in Realm with unique id. I use this code:

```
class Persons: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = 0
    @objc dynamic var name = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

and in my StorageManager I use this code:

```
import RealmSwift

let realm = try! Realm()

class StorageManager {
    static func saveObject(_ person: Persons) {
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(person)
        }
    }
    
    static func deleteObject(_ person: Persons) {
        try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(person)
        }
    }
}
```

But when I add second new object, I get error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason:
> 'Attempting to create an object of type 'Persons' with an existing
> primary key value '0'.'

How I can get new unique id for each new object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to let your code define that for you

```
class PersonClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var name = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

UUID().uuidString returns a unique string of characters which are perfect for primary keys.

**HOWEVER**

That won't work for Realm Sync in the future. MongoDB Realm is the new product and objects need to have a specific primary key property called _id which should be populated with the Realm ObjectID Property. So this is better if you want future compatibility

```
class PersonClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var _id = ObjectId()
    @objc dynamic var name = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "_id"
    }
}
```

You can read more about it in the [MongoDB Realm Getting Started Guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/objects/#primary-key)

Note that after RealmSwift 10.10.0, the following can be used to auto-generate the objectId

```
@Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
```

Keeping in mind that if `@Persisted` is used on an object then *all* of the Realm managed properties need to be defined with `@Persisted`

Note if using @Persisted then the `override static func primaryKey()` function is not needed

Comment: Also note that ObjectId's aren't automatically generated by Realm and we need to generate a new ID for each object at creation with ObjectId.generate().

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the comment! `ObjectId.generate()` was depreciated in [10.10.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/releases/tag/v10.10.0) because it would cause ObjectId's to be generated when they were not used. Since this post we can now use the following for the primary key `@Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId`.  I updated the answer with more current info - catching that was much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The better answer since Realm v10 came out is to use the dedicated new [objectID class](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Classes/ObjectId.html)

*A 12-byte (probably) unique object identifier.*

*ObjectIds are similar to a GUID or a UUID, and can be used to uniquely identify objects without a centralized ID generator. An ObjectID consists of:*

- *A 4 byte timestamp measuring the creation time of the ObjectId in seconds since the Unix epoch.*
- *A 5 byte random value*
- *A 3 byte counter, initialized to a random value.*

*ObjectIds are intended to be fast to generate. Sorting by an ObjectId field will typically result in the objects being sorted in creation order.*